# ST Link V2 "No STLink detected" in STM32CubeIDE and ST Link Utility

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide, st-link

The device was working fine till last week, now when I try to debug the STM32cubeIDE indicates "No ST Link found". On hardware side, there are no LED glowing on the STLink board.

Before concluding that the STLink V2 is dead, I would like to check if there are any workaround to try to revive the device, if I try to upgrade the firmware, then the STlink V2 is not detected as expected. The same observation is in the ST Link Utility tool.
Is there any other way that I can try, request for suggestions and help.

I am using windows10 PC.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it an original or pirat Chinese copy of st-link board?

Comment: Its original stlink V2 board

Comment: Did you install the drivers?

Comment: Yes I had installed all necessary drivers, as said it was totally working fine till last week. And I had been using this board from a long time.

Comment: Then it is dead  ⛼

Comment: Do you see ST-Link in your PC's device manager?

Answer (score 0):

**Things to check**

- Change the USB-cable with a known working one! Even USB-cables get defect. It took a colleague of mine some time to find a short in a USB-cable.
- Check the windows 10 device manager: Under USB-devices a *STM32 STLink* should be visible.
- Unplug/replug the board while you are in device manager. Is there some change in the device list (driver issue)?

When the device manager shows the *STM32 STLink* you also could try the [STM32CubeProgrammer](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeprog.html). Different tools from ST behave differently.